# Convert Week NUM to the Week Beg date in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the below formula to give me the week ending of a week num, how can I get the date of the week beginning from this?

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1)+(7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1))-6)+(A2*7)
```

when A2 is 10 for example and B2 is the date.

thanks

Comment: How are your week numbers defined.

Answer (score 0):

Are your weeks `ISO` weeks? If so then that formula might work for this year but it will be wrong in `2016` because it will give the end date of week 1 as `3rd Jan` when it should be `10th Jan`

I would use this formula for start date (a Monday)

`=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,A2*7-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,3))`

then just add 6 for the end date

`=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,A2*7+4)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,3))`